# MySQL cross table update using WHERE

Tags: mysql

Here's a simple query for updating table `product` with data from `helper`.

```
UPDATE product p 
INNER JOIN helper h ON p.productcode = h.productcode
SET p.picture = h.picture;
```

But if I add `WHERE p.gotpicture=0` at the end to update only the records with p.gotpicture=0 and not the entire table, then the query updates 0 rows. Why?

Comment: Have you verified the corresponding SELECT statement returns multiple rows? i.e. `SELECT p.picture, h.picture FROM product p INNER JOIN helper h ON p.productcode = h.productcode WHERE p.gotpicture=0 `

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * product p INNER JOIN helper h ON p.productcode = h.productcode WHERE p.gotpicture=0`?  Does it return any records?

Comment: @StephLocke - lol - Great minds... :)

Comment: Works fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c1e7/1

Comment: Is there any trigger on `products`?

Comment: What happens if you try `UPDATE product p 
INNER JOIN helper h ON p.productcode = h.productcode AND p.gotpicture=0
SET p.picture = h.picture;` Shouldn't make a difference but just want to double check.

Comment: @YaK: No, there arent any triggers. Kickstart: nothing.

Comment: Are the values of p.picture already set to the values of h.picture? If so no rows would be affected by the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'v tester and it's works fine for me.

But you can test these :

```
UPDATE product p , helper h
SET p.picture = h.picture
WHERE p.gotpicture=0 
AND p.productcode = h.productcode;
```

Or

```
UPDATE product p 
SET p.picture = (select h.picture from helper h where p.productcode = h.productcode)
WHERE p.gotpicture=0 
AND p.productcode in (select  h.productcode from helper h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very easily solved,just follow this..

```
 UPDATE product p,helper h

   SET p.picture = h.picture

     where p.productcode = h.productcode

       and p.gotpicture=0;
```

Just try this above code,You surely will be able to overcome your problem.